# Undefined Reference to '_method'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I believe something very odd is happening with my compiler options. When I compile `class.c` it compiles without error. However, when I try to create the `.dll` I get many errors:

```
undefined reference to '_method'
```

`_method` is any number of methods in class.c

I compile my code with the following:

```
gcc -c -g -w -I/path to include dir/include -MMD -MP -MF .../class.o.d -o class.o class.c
```

My link syntax is as follows:

```
gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -m32 -shared -o dist/libdt.dll class.o
```

To give an example, one of the undefined references is `undefined refence to '_min_size'` In `class.c`, however, it looks like:

```
if(min_size){ dsize=min_size; }
```

There is no underscore before the `min_size` in `class.c`. I'm sure this has something to do with my compile/link syntax but I just don't see it. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

PS: I'm using Netbeans and Cygwin.

Comment: how and where did you define min_size?

Comment: Sorry left that out. In an included file: class.h. It's of type size_t

Comment: But undefined references have nothing to do with include/header files.

Comment: You have to link ALL your files, not just your main class, that's the error, btw.

Comment: There is no main in class.c. I was just trying to test things out with the one class. Do you mean that in order to create the dll I need more than one file? That seems odd. OR do you mean I need to include class.h in the link syntax?

Comment: the compiler doesn't use the include file, or it doesn't know what size_t is at the point of the declaration of min_size and treats it as an external variable.

Comment: @redhotspike While you _can_, you're not supposed to define stuff in .h files, only declare stuff there.  How did you define min_size there, and does class.c include that particular .h file ?

Comment: @nos I have in class.h: extern size_t min_size; In my class.c I have: #include "class.h"

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding why the compiler is adding the '_' when it creates class.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _ is just a prefix that the stdcall calling convention on windows requires, that the compiler adds.

If you have extern size_t min_size; , you've only declared the min_size. i.e. you've told the compiler that somewhere there will be a size_t min_size; defined. You have to actually define that variable somewhere (e.g. in your class.c, put size_t min_size; there.)

Comment: *smacks forehead* lol I am really rusty with C. @nos Thank you. You've nailed it. There was no definition of min_size in class.c. Good grief...

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I went through my compiler options again because something was still bugging me about the options I provided. I figured it out: in my class.h file, I had some `#if defined(__STRICT_ANSI__)` and `#if defined(__WIN32__)` statements: I never defined that those were set.

For future reference my compiler options I now provide are:

```
gcc -ansi -Wall -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align -Wimplicit -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wno-parentheses -DFIFO -D__Win32__ -D_NT_SOURCE -c -o class.o class.c
```

After changing the compiler options, I no longer got any errors about undefined references! I hope this helps some people out in the future. :)